# How to get text nested into TH without text nested in TH's children nodes?

Tags: javascript, html

I parse some site and getting TH element instance, then I use innerText to get needed text, the problem comes when there is some additional junk text that I don't need. Is there anyway I can get top level text only?

```
var th_elem = /*some_calls*/;
var my_text = th_elem.innerText; //Oh no, this has extra text that I don't need.
```

I don't know what extra text is, so I can't always remove it by it's common lenth.

[image]

Comment: `.firstChild.data` might do - it selects the first child node (usually a text node) and gets its content.

Comment: @Bergi - `var my_text = th_elem.firstChild.data;`?

Comment: ^ looks correct to me.

Comment: @Kosmos Yes, does it work?

Comment: @Bergi - I can't believe, but it's work! Thank you. Make it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to get the text from the first text node, then select that node using by using the [`.firstChild` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild). You can get its contents from its [`.data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData#Properties), [`.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) or [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property.

```
var my_text = th_elem.firstChild.data;
```